# How can a List of INDArrays be stored in a file

Tags: java, deeplearning4j

I am working on an reinforcement-learning project and have a `List<INDArray>` which holds a list of states of the world and a second `List<INDArray>`which holds action-prediction and reward values with the index corresponding to the states of the first `List`

I want to store these data for later training on the hard-drive, how can I achieve this?

Lets sax for example we have:

```
List<INDArray> stateList = new ArrayList<>();
stateList.add(Nd4j.valueArrayOf(new int[]{3,3,3}, 5));
stateList.add(Nd4j.valueArrayOf(new int[]{3,3,3}, 6));

List<INDArray> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
valueList.add(Nd4j.create(new float[]{1, 2}));
valueList.add(Nd4j.create(new float[]{3, 4}));
```

Comment: You wrote: _I want to store these data for later training on the hard-drive_ Do you mean you want to write the `List` contents to a file?

Comment: @Abra that's correct

Comment: `ArrayList` is serializable. Is that not an option?

Answer (score 0):

you have to preparefile content and then simply write into file.

```
        String fileContent = "";
        for (INDArray arr : valueList) {
            str +=arr.getValue()+"/n";//arr.getValue() anything which u want to add
        }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("c:/temp/samplefile.txt");
        fileWriter.write(fileContent);
        fileWriter.close();
```